# Oracle BigData Lite with Windows Active Directory

Tags: oracle, hadoop, ssl, active-directory, ldap

I am currently trying to use Oracle BigData Lite VM to simulate connectivity with **Windows Active Directory(Windows Server 2012)** on another VM.

Both VMs are on Oracle VBox. However it kept giving me this error when i used cloudera manager in the Lite VM to enable kerberos:

```
/usr/share/cmf/bin/import_credentials.sh: line 84: ldapsearch: command not found
```

- echo 'ldapsearch did not work with SASL authentication. Trying with simple authentication'
- echo 'Failed to do ldapsearch.'
- echo 'Please make sure Active Directory configuration is correctly specified and LDAP over SSL is enabled.'

I am guessing that I need to configure the `SSL portion` before enabling kerberos? Btw, I am **able to telnet** over to Windows AD. If so, how do I go about doing it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check whether the `ldapsearch` command-line utility was installed on your VM? And whether it was in the PATH of the Linux user used by Cloudera Manager?

Comment: I tried running ldapsearch in cmd and it works. So I suppose ldapsearch is installed?

Comment: *"in cmd"* -- you mean you tried **on your bloody Windows PC**?!?